# What was the Halacha before the ruling of "יהרג ואל יעבר"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-sanhedrin

> The Sages counted the votes and concluded: If a person is told: Transgress this prohibition and you will not be killed, he may transgress, except for idol worship, forbidden sexual relations, and bloodshed. [Sanhedrin.74a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.74a?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi)

Was there a ruling Halacha before that assembly, or did every rabbi follow his own understanding, as the Gemmarah in place discusses many different opinions about that ruling?

Comment: I would assume וחי בהם would apply to all מצוות without exceptions

Comment: There was https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97407/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12311/759

Comment: Like you said, the vote was to negate the opposing opinions (such as Rabbi Yishmael, who says that one should worship idols rather than die). This is like any other machlokes, no? Each community followed its Rabbi, until the manner was decided upon by the Sanhedrin.

Comment: From Rambam in introduction to the Mishnah כאשר מת יהושע בן נון ע"ה למד לזקנים מה שקבל מן הפירוש ומה שהוציאו בזמנו מן הדינים ולא נפל עליו מחלוקת. ואשר נפל בו מחלוקת פסקו בו הדין על פי רוב הזקנים. ועליהם אמר הכתוב (יהושע כד) וכל ימי הזקנים אשר האריכו ימים אחרי יהושע. ואחר כן למדו הזקנים ההם מה שקבלו מפי יהושע אל הנביאים ע"ה והנביאים למדו זה לזה.